# Google app engine can't switched to python3

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've following the instruction in:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart

But when I execute "python" the version number still show 2.7.9, I've checked the app.yaml, it already set the python_version: 3

Comment: Yes, but the error prompt, File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'. Beside, the document didn't state python3 should be used

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I found that if I execute python main.py and browser :80, the python will run in python2, but if I execute "gcloud app deploy" and "gcloud app browse" then it will run in python3